# How do you get UID:GID in the [1002120000, 1002129999] range to make it run in OpenShift?

Tags: docker, filesystems, openshift, acl, mosquitto

This is with OpenShift Container Platform **4.3**.

Consider this `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM eclipse-mosquitto

# Create folders
USER root

RUN mkdir -p /mosquitto/data /mosquitto/log

# mosquitto configuration
USER mosquitto

# This is crucial to me
COPY --chown=mosquitto:mosquitto ri45.conf /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf

EXPOSE 1883
```

And, this is my `Deployment` YAML.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-broker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mosquitto-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mosquitto-broker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mosquitto-broker
          image: org/repo/eclipse-mosquitto:1.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mosquitto-data
              mountPath: /mosquitto/data
            - name: mosquitto-log
              mountPath: /mosquitto/log
          ports:
            - name: mqtt
              containerPort: 1883
      volumes:
        - name: mosquitto-log
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mosquitto-log
        - name: mosquitto-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mosquitto-data
```

When I do a `oc create -f` with the above YAML, I get this error, `2020-06-02T07:59:59: Error: Unable to open log file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log for writing.` *Maybe* this is a permissions error; can't tell. Anyway, going by the [`eclipse/mosquitto` `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/docker/1.5/Dockerfile), I see that `mosquitto` is a user with UID and GID of `1883`. So, I added the `securityContext` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58751291/919480).

```yaml
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 1883
```

When I do a `oc create -f` with this modification, I get this error - `securityContext.securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1883: must be in the ranges: [1002120000, 1002129999]`.

This [approach of adding an `initContainer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51195446/919480) to set permissions on volume does not work for me because, I have to be `root` to do that.

So, how do I enable the Eclipse mosquitto container to write to `/mosquitto/log` successfully?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple things to address here.

First off, you should make sure that you really want to bake a configuration file into your container image. Typically, configuration files are added via `ConfigMaps` or `Secrets`, as the [configuration in cloud-native applications should typically come from the environment](https://12factor.net/config) (OpenShift in your case).

Secondly, it seems that you are logging into a `PersistentVolume`, which is also a terrible practice, as the [best practice](https://12factor.net/logs) would be to log to `stdout`. Of course, having application data (transaction logs) on a persistent volume makes sense.

As for your original question (that should no longer be relevant given the two points above), the issue can be approached using `SecurityContextContraints` (SCCs): [Managing Security Context Constraints](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html#security-context-constraints-about_configuring-internal-oauth)

So to resolve your issue you should use / create a SCC with `runAsUser` set correctly.

Comment: The logging problem can be fixed  with `log_dest stdout` in the config file. But you'll still need permission to write the mosquitto persistent file for the sessions and retained messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option. In fact, now, for some reason, `log_timestamp_format` is not even recognized by the `mosquitto` Docker image! This is the image I built with the base Dockerfile.